# What Web Application Firewall can be used for Apache Tomcat?

Tags: java, apache, security, tomcat

I was looking into ModSecurity to prevent XSS attacks on our Web Application, a WAF for Apache but I am quite confused as to how to install and since it requires Apache httpd but the server I am currently using is Apache Tomcat v.8 and a pre-requisite for ModSecurity is to have Apache 2.x or higher. Is there a WAF for Apache Tomcat or should I integrate Apache 2.x with my Apache Tomcat v.8 server and what is the difference between Apache 2.x with my Apache Tomcat server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apache (non tomcat) is 'just' a HTTP server, written in C, nothing to do with java, this is often called 'apache'.
Tomcat or 'Apache Tomcat' is a Servlet container for Java web applications AND an http server.
To use mod_security with Tomcat you'll probably want to install apache as a reverse proxy in front of tomcat.
Configuring mod_security (and deal with false positives) could be very difficult... and, even if good, the standard ruleset is not the final word against XSS (or sql injections etc).
My suggestion to avoid XXS in Tomcat is to apply right encode to HTML, HTML attributes, Javascript etc in the dynamic HTML pages.
You can accomplish that using a library like ESAPI: https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Category:OWASP_Enterprise_Security_API
Another approach is to use ThymeLeaf as a presentation engine instead of JSP. This will automatically encode output for you and it will be more effective against XXS.